# high volume transaction data informative pattern generation

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing, large-data-volumes

I am trying to figure out informative data patterns from large volume transactional data.

Typically my data is set of records with well defined columns (like sender, receiver, amount, currency address etc - I have around 40-50 different columns), data volume will be multi million (may be 100s of millions) records and my aim is to generate informative transactional patterns from this like - who is purchasing particular item the most, highest volume transaction recipients, expense patterns, who is getting more transactions from same another sender etc.

Earlier I was planning to load data in relational database (Oracle/MySQL) and write complex SQLs to fetch this information but by looking at volume during my proof of concept, it doesn't seem to be much scalable.

I was trying to get more information on distributive data processing using Hadoop etc. I just started reading Hadoop, up to my initial understanding Hadoop is well suited for unstrcutured data processing and might not be much useful for relational data processing.

Any pointers/suggestions on open source technology which I can quickly experiment with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop can be used for structured/unstructured data processing. Also, it's not a database to maintain relationships, indexes like a traditional RDBMS.

With millions of rows [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) or [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) coupled with/without [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) can be used for batch querying. Batch querying in Hadoop had been there for some time and is mature.

For interactive querying [Drill](http://incubator.apache.org/drill/) or [Imapala](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/cloudera-impala-real-time-queries-in-apache-hadoop-for-real/) can be used. Note that Drill development has just started and is in incubator stage. While, Imapala has been just announced by Cloudera. Here is [some](http://gigaom.com/data/cloudera-makes-sql-a-first-class-citizen-in-hadoop/) interesting [info](http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2012/10/cloudera-impala-hadoop/) for real time engines.

Note that there are lot of other open source frameworks which might fit the requirements, but only a couple of them are mentioned here. Based on detailed requirement analysis and the pros and cons of the different frameworks, the appropriate framework has to be chosen.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, Let me take a look at your links and get back with further questions.